# jQuery unable to pick dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss from a input bos

Tags: jquery, timepicker

I m timepicker plugin to pick values from a text field. jquery is able to pick the dd/mm/yy but it is not able to pick hh:mm:ss.
Further after firing from another event it is able to pick it seems the pick event is fired before the value is updated in field. 
How can i get over the problem

Comment: You'll have to provide some source code.

Comment: Could you make a http://jsfiddle.net/ to illustrate your problem?

Comment: This sounds like a perfectly legitimate question, but you need to provide some more information.